# Ruby rspec check string begins with certain values

Tags: ruby, regex, string, rspec

I have a string that begins with a set start and then is filled to 252 characters by randomly generated letters. (237 random chars - so that the end length is 252 characters)

For the purpose of testing the string starts off with `TESTDATAMENDNOW` and the rest is random capital letters.

How can I test that the characters are all capital letters
and that the string begins with `TESTDATAMENDNOW`

I have tried to use regex expressions to define this but I'm not too sure how to get them to work properly, and what I have tried so far seems not to be working.

EDIT: Clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expect(string).to match(/\ATESTDATAMENDNOW[A-Z]{237}\z/)
```

`237` because `252` minus the length of `"TESTDATAMENDNOW"` is `237`.

Comment: At first I had an error but it seems that you didnt take into account that the end string is 252 characters, not the random section, so it should be 237 instead

Comment: @SovietKetchup If this is not what you wanted, then it is your fault. If it should be 237, then you should have written so. It is also not clear what you mean by "end string" or "end length".

Comment: "then is filled to 252 characters" apologies if it wasn't very clear. I added some clarification to the original post

Comment: It is also not clear to me why you wrote `"TESTDATA"` and `"MENDNOW"` in two steps. Couldn't you just write that the string starts with `"TESTDATAMENDNOW"`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that does not use a regex:

```
str = "TESTDATAMENDNOW"
expect(string[0,str.size]).eq(str)
expect(string.delete("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ").eq("")
expect(string.size).eq(252)
```